# long to float conversion in linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, floating-point

It's my first question here, and I hope that I'll get useful answers or hints here.

As it's in the title: I need to convert from long to float in a kernel module, for example: 78123456 to 78.123456, and the details as follows:

1. I have two long variables (an out put of simple_strtol function) and I need to convert them to float (it's a required task in the project).
2. The exponent is fixed as 6 (6 numbers after the floating point).
3. (atof) doesn't work in kernel space.
4. I tried to make casting...it doesn't work.
5. I tried to times it by 0.000001, but float operations aren't available in kernel work.
6. Of course, I'm working in C programming language.

Please, if there is any way to do that let me know asap:

- if there is a function which I don't know (I don't thing there is one), what is it?
- if there is a function one library please tell me how can I download this library and how to include it.
- if there is any other method also tell me.

Any hint is really appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Given that floating-point support isn't available within the kernel, what do you plan to do with the float you end up with? (Does it actually need to be a float, or just displayed as one?)

Comment: Kernel and floating point is a no no because of the way that kernel space handles the FPU during context switch.

Comment: My task is to take latitude and longitude from text file and send them as floats  (mandatory)
I could copy the numbers (as characters) to /proc file, then read them, convert them from strings to longs (that what simple_strtol does, and I didn't find a function that converts to float)
the proplem that the task is to send them as floats

ohh...but the supervisor told me that I can use bytewise representation of floating point numbers...but it's not clear enough for me .. :(

another thing: to declare a float vaiable and send it is available, but floating operations aren't

Thank you very much.

Comment: what about using bytewise representation of floating point numbers

for me I have no idea about this work, how can I do something like this??

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem like it should be a kernel module at all.  The tidbits described seem like they would be part of a fine application program which formats and sends UDP packets.

If that isn't viable, perhaps a [FUSE-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) approach could be used instead?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you just want to display this variable with a decimal point (maybe the variable measures microseconds and you want to display in seconds) rather than actually manipulate the floating point variable (since you have already pointed out that floating point operations aren't available in the kernel space).

In this case, don't treat this problem as a conversion from long integer to floating point - instead treat it as a string manipulation problem, especially since your input to `strtol` is a string.

In pseudocode, if your input and output are separate strings:

```
void insertDecimalPoint(char const * strSrc, char * strDest, int maxlength)
{
    1. find the length of strSrc
    2. if length <= 6, then write a prefix of zeros like '0.000' to strDest
       and then copy the source string to the destination
    3. else, copy the first (length - 6) digits, then add a decimal point '.',
       then copy the rest of the source to the destination.
}
```

Alternatively, if you have the input as a long integer `val`, a line like

```
whole = val / 1e6;
fraction = val - whole * 1e6;
printf("%d.%06d", whole, fraction);
```

will do the right thing.

Comment: Ah, I see the question has been updated so my assumption is wrong.  For the bytewise representation of floats, here's a starting point: http://www.psc.edu/general/software/packages/ieee/ieee.php

Comment: Thank you very much
- But the task ins't to display anything, I have to send longitude and latitude coordinates, as floats, inside IP datagram.
- I already recieves value in "float-like string" (78.123456 but as string of characters) from /proc file, because I could get just strings from /proc file.
- If i can create float buffer to get from /proc file my problem will be solved.
- I have another choice to deal with bytewise representaion of floationg numbers...but I don't know how.

Thank you for your trying to help

Comment: I wrote my comment before reading your comment
I'll see the link right now
Thanks alot :)